# Fisher Projection vs Linear Discriminant Analysis

Tags: r, data-mining, dimensionality-reduction, discriminant-analysis

Basically, I am confused between Fisher and LDA. Looking for differences between the two.

How is the Fischer projection computed in R?

Comment: Fischer projection is a concept from chemistry - how to draw a 3d molecule in 2d. Do you mean the statistician Fisher, who investigated LDA?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Fischer Projection**: Suggests maximizing the difference between the means,normalized by a measure of the within-class scatter.

**Linear Discriminant Analysis**: seeks to reduce dimensionality while preserving as much of the class discriminatory information as possible.

So, Fischer Projection method is one of the solutions for Discriminant Analysis.

[R package](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/MASS/html/lda.html) for carrying out LDA.
This [tutorial](http://www.r-bloggers.com/an-example-of-linear-discriminant-analysis/) on R-bloggers would give you a better idea about the concept, and it's application in R.

Comment: Glad it helped.

Comment: Shouldn't it be Fisher not Fischer? See my comment under the question.

Comment: Ohh, that "c" has created a confusion. It might be "Fisher" too.  Maybe only @Disha would be able to tell.

As Fischer and LDA have close relation, I assumed it as "Fischer"